# Web Console Warnings and Errors

Tags: javascript, console, warnings, mozilla

I'm working on my new Joomla site; Actually I've faced with an strange problem, Sometimes my site's home-page loads incompletely and It's obvious that codes (specially javascript files) are stopped while page loading.
In this situation, I can open "CONSOLE" of MOZILLA browser and see some errors related to the some JS files, like these:

- TypeError: jQuery(...).mixItUp is not a function[Learn More]
- HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
  n2.js:12
- TypeError: jQuery(...).fitVids is not a function[Learn More]
- TypeError: wrapper.getElement(...) is null[Learn More]
- TypeError: wrapper.getElement(...) is null[Learn More]
  engine.js:61:14

**But when I refresh the page, these error will be disappeared and I can't see them until the next loading-problem of the page.**

How can I diagnosis the issues?

https://nadbranding.com

Best regards

Comment: Probably some network issues..

Comment: Thanks a lot; But I have the bad page-loading as a routine issue. Also console shows some TypeError messages that are code structural problem in Javascripts.

Comment: Seems like you have periodically some troubles with loading of 'jquery' library. Try to use some better/stable CDN service. For example [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/) or [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)